# Fs2 how to fold then append to a Stream

Tags: scala, fs2

I want to append to a `Stream`

But next stream relies on previous `Stream`'s folding result

Here is how I did, but the Stream `s` is evaluated twice

[scasite link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/NTe0CetNQIarcStYx0RiTg)

```
import fs2._

def ints(start: Int) = Stream.iterate(start) { i => 
  println(i)
  i + 1
}.take(10)

val s = ints(0)

def foldAppend(init: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Int)(next: Int => Stream[Pure, Int]) = {
  s ++ s.fold(init)(f).flatMap(next)
}

val res = foldAppend(0)((s, i) => s + 1)(ints)
println(res.toList)
```

How can I implement the `foldAppend` method that evalute `s` only once.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't write `def s` instead of `val s`? As it stands, I'm not sure there's enough information to answer this question. A complete example would be helpful, meaning a full definition of `s`.

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I've add the scasite link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally get work done with `Pull`

```
implicit class StreamSyntax[F[_], A](s: Stream[F, A]) {
    def foldAppend[S](init: S)(f: (S, A) => S)(next: S => Stream[F, A]): Stream[F, A] = {

      def pullAll(s: Stream[F, A]): Pull[F, A, Option[(Chunk[A], Stream[F, A])]] = {
        s.pull.unconsChunk.flatMap {
          case Some((hd, tl)) =>
            Pull.output(hd) *> pullAll(tl)
          case None =>
            Pull.pure(None)
        }
      }

      def foldChunks(i: S, s: Stream[F, A]): Pull[F, A, Option[(Chunk[A], Stream[F, A])]] = {
        s.pull.unconsChunk.flatMap {
          case Some((hd, tl)) =>
            val sum: S = hd.toVector.foldLeft(i)(f)
            Pull.output(hd) *> foldChunks(sum, tl)
          case None =>
            pullAll(next(i))
        }
      }
      foldChunks(init, s).stream
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer is wrong, `s` is actually lazy so the entire stream is evaluated twice. The variable binding to `s` is strict, but `Stream` in fs2 is a lazy stream, that is only evaluated once you `run` it.

Your main issue is that `Pure` is not a monad for implementing side effect safely, like `IO`. You shouldn't `println` in pure. An example that works is:

```
import cats.effect.IO
import fs2._

def ints(start: Int) = Stream.iterate(start) { i => println(i)
  i + 1
}.take(10)

val s = ints(0)

def foldAppend(init: Int)(f: (Int, Int) => Int)(next: Int => Stream[IO, Int]) = {

  val result = s.covary[IO].runLog
  Stream.eval(result).covary[IO].flatMap {
    s =>
      Stream.emits(s) ++ Stream.emits(s).fold(init)(f).flatMap(next)
  }
}
val res = foldAppend(0)((s, i) => s + 1)(ints)
println(res.runLast.unsafeRunSync())
```

This will evaluate the stream once

Comment: I use `println` just to indicate that the stream is evaluated twice

Comment: This solution actually will first store all data into memory, then emits to a new `Stream`, I am afraid it can not scale.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using `scala.collection.immutable.Stream`? It's cached, so it won't be evaluated multiple times.